# OnMessage() functionality for UDP

Tags: java, websocket, udp

I was wondering if there is a type of OnMessage() type functionality for UDP messages using DatagramPacket? I want to be able to ensure that I get all messages when they come across so I don't waste resources randomly grabbing on a timer.

The OnMessage I am referring to the one done in WebSocketClient. Or some functionality similar to "Available" in .net.

```
While (rxUdpClient.Available > 0)
```

I am monitoring several ports so a thread is called which will do a run() for each port. Problem is I seem to have messages coming in at a massive rate 40+/sec.

This is what I currently have:

```
public void run()
{
    DatagramSocket sock = null;       
        sock = new DatagramSocket(port);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DataAdapterFB1.HEADER_SIZE + DataAdapterFB1.MAX_DATA_BYTES];
    DatagramPacket incoming = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    while (true){           
        sock.receive(incoming);           
        byte[] data = incoming.getData();
        String s = new String(data, 0, incoming.getLength());
        //This is the processing code, but it isn't its own thread...
        ScadaMsg newMessage = new ScadaMsg(data);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DatagramPacket* receive() operation is blocking, so what you will normally do is just launch a separate thread, which will listen for the incoming datagrams in a loop and dispatch them for further processing, like that:

```
void run() {
    socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);

    while(true) {
         byte[] buf = new byte[256];
         DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
         socket.receive(packet); //JVM will wait here, until there is an incoming packet
         onMessage(packet.getData())
    }
 } 

 public abstract void onMessage(final byte[] pkt);
```

Comment: Then you should be all set, as socket.receive() will make JVM subscribe to the OS socket , and will get the data once it arrives.
There is no timer involved and no resources "wasted".

Comment: Issue being I seem to be missing packets. They are coming in too fast or something?

Comment: Scratch that. The output was going by so fast it looked like it was missing items, but once I removed the sleep that I had in there and looked back at the output, it is now catching them all. Thanks zeppelin!

Comment: You are welcome. 
> They are coming in too fast or something?
Actually that can be the case sometimes, so you should watch your "RecieveBufferSize" (setReceiveBufferSize()/getReceiveBufferSize()), 
and maybe also process the data async (via Executor e.t.c.)